# cannot acces http://server_domain_or_IP:8000

Tags: django, web-deployment, azure-virtual-machine, server-configuration, ipconfig

I am using an AzureVM to host my development API server written in django.
There, I cloned my codebase and did all the requirements.txt installation. Before executing the `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` command, I changed the firewall permission rule: `sudo ufw allow 8000`.
The `sudo ufw status` commads shows the following result:

```bash
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and then I run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

I should be able to see the default django page @ `http://SERVER_IP_OR_DOMAIN:8000`
But nothing shows.
whereas if I hit `http://SERVER_IP_OR_DOMAIN`, I can see the NGINX landing page.

I am following this blog from [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Here is my VM network rules:
[image: VM network rules]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

[image]

To resolve this issue:

In your virtual machine make sure to ***Add inbound port*** ***Destination port ranges as 8000*** like below:

[image]

Comment: I added the inbound port for TCP 8000 and it worked fine. That solved the problem.Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I edited your answer. The part that answered